# Define several modules in a single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, autoload

Is it possible to merge multiple module definitions in a single file and avoid possible clashes with Rails autoloading ?

Thanks !

Comment: all constants defined in any file that is required will be available. local variables and naked `def`s won't be.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood how this would help *“to avoid possible clashes with Rails autoloading”*, but the answer is “yes”: one might define as many modules, classes, constants and whatever is defineable in the single file.

Ruby has no restriction on the relation between file names and modules/classes names. One might define modules `A1` and `A2` in file `b.rb`. Standard `lib/namespace/class_name.rb` convetion is the convention only, as soon as file is required, it’s content is being loaded.